# Как отобразить состояние батарейки на desktop приложении в qml?

Tags: c++, windows, qml

Хочу отобразить состояние вайфая, батареи итд..
Есть модуль QtMobility (там по описанию есть то что мне нужно ). Честно сказать, я не знаю где его искать. Пробовал просто подключить в qml

```
import QtMobility.systeminfo 1.2

... do 
BatteryInfo {
    id: batinfo
    monitorChargerTypeChanges: true
    monitorChargingStateChanges: true
}
```

выдает ошибку

```
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtMobility.systeminfo" is not installed
```

Это какой то сторонний модуль?
Нашел что то очень похожее на одном известном сайте
https://github.com/taladar/qtmobility

это то что мне надо?

Comment: Если вопрос про qml - не вкурсе. На плюсах (т.к. стоит метка `с++`) - под виндой из WMI можно достать без проблем, так же можно через WINAPI http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus

Comment: плюсы да. Забыл поставить метку кроссплатформенность :) Я думал тоже использовать winapi но это придется перекрывать дефайнами что не есть хорошо